# Example code of the Thinknum package does not run

Tags: r, finance

The following example code in the documentation of the Thinknum package

```
install.packages("Thinknum")
library(Thinknum)
thinknumdata = Thinknum("total_revenue(goog)")
```

leads on my machine to the following error:

```
Error in Thinknum("total_revenue(goog)") : Requested Expression does not exist.
```

It would help me a lot, if one or more people could run the example code on another machine.

Comment: Confirmed.  It doesn't run.  You will need to contact the package maintainer and tell them that `example(Thinknum, run.dontrun = TRUE)` returns an error.  There's nothing that users here can do about that.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but if you go to http://data.thinknum.com/api/v1/?expression=total_revenue%28goog%29, which is what the function is doing, there is no data.  And that error is triggered by `if (length(json$data) == 0)` so the function worked.  And that's all I have to say about that :)

Comment: This question is probably more suitable as a support request for the thinknum.com people.